# Display where function is called from not where it is defined console javascript

Tags: javascript, console

I am a lazy developer... I like to make shortcuts, so I bound console.info to `c`

```
  /*core_functions.js*/
 /*==================================================
 Bind C to be alert on mobile console.log in desktop
 ================================================== */
window.c = false;
if (typeof console === "object" && typeof console.error === "function" && !SP.isMobile) {
    c = function (msg) {
        console.info(msg);
    };
} else {
    c = function (msg) {
        debug(msg);
    };
}

  /*somefile.js*/
  c(anObject);
```

I have been using this for quite some time and something has always annoyed me. It displays the file in which the function is defined rather than where the function is called from:

```
core_functions.js:40 Object {stadiumname: "Stadium 3", pitch: Object, lights: Object, seats: Object, scoreboards: Object…}
```

Can I reference where the function is being called from? Or am I forever stuck with this minor annoyance?

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing that line number because it really is where `console.info` is called. A way I can think to avoid that is by calling the real `console` method rather than proxying with an intermediate function.

It seems to me you want to have an abstraction layer to handle your logging using the native console or a custom one.

In that case you could try something like this:

```
var c = (typeof console === 'object') ? console : alternative;
```

And then use it as:

```
c.log('Hello World');
```

That way your alternative object could be one with the methods you are considering on using, for instance:

```
var alternative = {
    log: function() {
        window.alert.apply(window, arguments);
    }
};
```

This way you won't get your `c()` function but, I think, you'll end up with a more flexible solution. By exposing the same interface that `console` has you could even add these logging facilities to any code running in your app (that is, 3rd party code using native `console`)

```
window.console = (typeof window.console === 'object') ? window.console : alternative
```

or if you are feeling very lazy that day :)

```
window.console = window.console || alternative
```

This is no perfect technique at all but if you are only using it while developing it might help.

Also, I never really participate in Stack Overflow so I'm very sorry if I'm ignoring any rule or etiquette :)

Comment: No etiquettes at all. Interesting idea to only expose the console and reference the functions you need. That does mean typing an extra 4 characters... I will have to play and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to get backtraces, you might be able to do something with it.

```
arguments.callee.caller.toString()
```